# Adding Availability Set To Azure Virtual Machine Template Creation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-availability-set

I can create a Azure VM with a specific VHD from the template below but how do I also add it to an Availability Set.  I can't do this after VM creation so I need to do it here.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location to create the VM in"
            }
        },
        "osDiskVhdUri": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Uri of the existing VHD"
            }
        },
        "osType": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Windows",
                "Linux"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Type of OS on the existing vhd"
            }
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_D2",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Size of the VM"
            }
        },
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the VM"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "api-version": "2015-06-15",
        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "subnetName": "Subnet",
        "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
        "publicIPAddressName": "specializedVMPublicIP",
        "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
        "virtualNetworkName": "specializedVMVNET",
        "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName'))]",
        "nicName": "specializedVMNic"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[parameters('osDiskVhdUri')]"
                        },
                        "createOption": "Attach"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure things like this out is to poke through the [templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) until you find what you need!

So according to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-availability-set-create-3FDs-20UDs/azuredeploy.json) template, you create an Availability Set like this

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
    "name": "availabilitySet1",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
      "platformFaultDomainCount": "3",
      "platformUpdateDomainCount": "20"
    }
  }
]
```

and then (according to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/875d139c16c9c023dce519e6dd48c707e3473346/201-vm-copy-index-loops/azuredeploy.json)) you use it like this

```
"apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"name": "[concat('myvm', copyIndex())]",
"location": "[variables('location')]",
"copy": {
  "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
  "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
},
"dependsOn": [
  "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', 'nic', copyindex())]",
  "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
],
"properties": {
  "availabilitySet": {
    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be looking at the Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets resource provider, here is some sample JSON from one of my templates.

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
  "name": "availabilitySet1",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "platformFaultDomainCount": "3",
    "platformUpdateDomainCount": "20"
  }
}
]
```

You then need to use the `availabilitySet` property of the `virtualMachines` resource provider to add the VMs to the availability set. Make sure you use `dependsOn` to ensure the availability set is created before the VM. As an example if you refering to it by name:

```
"properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": { "vmSize": "Standard_A0" },
        "networkProfile": ...,
        "availabilitySet": { "id": "availabilitySet1" },
}
```